# Solve $3x^3=({x^2+\sqrt{18}x+\sqrt{32}})(x^2-\sqrt{18}x-\sqrt{32})-4x^2$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

Solve for $x$ in

$$3x^3=({x^2+\sqrt{18}x+\sqrt{32}})(x^2-\sqrt{18}x-\sqrt{32})-4x^2$$

I'm really not good with 4th degree equations but since the 1st term in the RHS looked a simple (a+b)(a-b) application, I tried solving that but I'm really not able to reach to the final answer as it only gets more complicated...
can anyone please help me out?
The equation I got was:

$$x^4-3x^3-22x^2-48x-32=0$$

Comment: Can you show what you tried with the simple (a+b)(a-b) application?

Comment: alright! I'll put the equation in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand $$x^4-3 x^3-22 x^2-48 x-32=0$$
Try to factorize $$x^4-3 x^3-22 x^2-48 x-32=\left(a x+b+x^2\right) \left(c x+d+x^2\right)$$
RHS gives $$x^4+x^3 (a+c)+x^2 (a c+b+d)+x (a d+b c)+b d$$
thus we must have

$$
\begin{cases}
a+c=-3\\
ac+b+d=-22\\
ad+bc=-48\\
bd=-32\\
\end{cases}
$$

Final factorization should be
$$\left(x^2-6 x-8\right) \left(x^2+3 x+4\right)=0$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that the given equation

$$3x^3=({x^2+\sqrt{18}x+\sqrt{32}})(x^2-\sqrt{18}x-\sqrt{32})-4x^2$$

is purposefully structured to allow convenient factorization as follows

$$3x^3=x^4-(\sqrt{18}x+\sqrt{32})^2 -4x^2$$
$$x^4-3x^3-4x^2-(\sqrt{18}x+\sqrt{32})^2 =0$$
$$x^4-(3x+4)x^2-2(3x+4)^2 =0$$
$$(x^2+(3x+4))(x^2-2(3x+4))=0$$

Comment: Oh wow, that's a nice observation! I was hoping for that, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, show what you've tried.)

1. Expanding everything, the equation is
   $$ x^4 - 3x^3 - 22x^2 - 48x - 32 = 0. $$
2. Factorize this.
3. Apply the quadratic formula to find the roots.

Comment: By Gauss's Lemma the only possible (integer) roots are the divisors of $32$ which are powers of $2$.

Comment: yes but out of the four roots, two are complex and the other two are real... is there an easier way to factorise this? or some other way to get those kind of complex roots?

Comment: I suppose getting the answer from wolfram alpha would be cheating?

Comment: Well, there is a way, you could write $x^4-3x^3-22x^2-48x-32=(x^2+bx+c)(x^2+b'x+c')$, then $-3=b+b'$, $-22=c+c'+bb'$, $-48=cb'+c'b$ and $-32=cc'$, and try to find $b,b',c,c'\in\mathbb Z$

Comment: @MatíasUres Right. If nothing obvious seems to work, then I use trial and error, often focusing on the last term $ cc' = 32$ to restrict what to look at. In this case, it can be done pretty quickly.